# Validar usuario Active Directory en servidor externo

Tags: php, xml, webservice, login

tengo una aplicación en php y necesito validar el login contra un servidor Active Directory, eso ya lo he hecho cuando los dos servidores está en local, pero en este caso no lo están y no me abren puerto del servidor Active Directory por seguridad.
Me comentan que en estos casos se utiliza un gateway o pasarela, algo similar a lo que usan sistemas como Teamviewer, pero no se muy bien como se puede implementar.
Otra opción que he visto sería crear un webservice en el servidor donde esta el Active Directory, pero para acceder a él necesitaré que habrán el puerto correspondiente.

Alguna idea?
gracias

Answer (score 0):

las tecnologías de autenticación con Active Directory fueron diseñadas para red interna, al intentar hacer un login desde fuera de la red con credenciales del Active Directory pues generas un innecesario y potencial riesgo de seguridad no solo en tu sistema también en el sistema completo de (posiblemente) una compañía. Dicho eso si aún quieres continuar puedes hacerlo de forma sencilla con un WebService y tecnología LDAP, te dejo un link de referencia

[Application-Login-through-Active-Directory-LDAP](https://codeproject.com/Tips/458039/Application-Login-through-Active-Directory-LDAP)

NOTA: este WebService es con tecnología .NET

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por contestar! Voy a echar un vistazo a lo que me has facilitado a ver si me puede servir ;)